# How to echo Check box text using Pop Up in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code having a button. When button is clicked a modal will show. On modal, there are multiple check-boxes. When one of the check-boxes is checked, a value of that check-box should print. **But I want to print Text of clicked Checkbox.**

[**[Please Check This Fiddle]**](https://jsfiddle.net/6me6sjex/9/)

Here is my code

```
$(document)
  .ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
      maxWidth: 800,
      maxHeight: 600,
      fitToView: false,
      width: '70%',
      height: '70%',
      autoSize: false,
      closeClick: false,
      openEffect: 'none',
      closeEffect: 'none'
    });

    $('.button1').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.various').click();
    });

  })
  .on('change', '[name=test-link]', function() {
    $('#print-values').empty();
    $('#print-values').append("<span>You've checked:</span><br />");
    $('[name=test-link]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        var v = $(this).val();
        $('#print-values').append(v + "<br />");
      }
    });
  });




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<a class="various" href="#form1" style='display: none;'></a>
<input class='button1' type="button" value="Link More Opinion" />
<div id='print-values'></div>
<div style='display: none;'>
  <form id='form1'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='test-link' value="1" /> One

    <br />
    <input type='checkbox' name='test-link' value="2" />Two
    <br />
    <input type='checkbox' name='test-link' value="3" /> Three
    <br />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm adding `id` https://jsfiddle.net/6me6sjex/12/ in your checkbox

Comment: @Boby its not working

Comment: What does it mean `But I want to print Text of clicked Checkbox` ?.  Like this https://jsfiddle.net/6me6sjex/14 ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
var v = $(this).val();
```

with it:

```
var v = $(this)[0].nextSibling.nodeValue;
```

Comment: Dear it print Text but it also change the value into text

Answer (score 0):

You could use a data attribute on your checkboxes to provide you with the right text to show.

Check my forked fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eLozh9zd/1/

```
<input type='checkbox' name='test-link' value="1" data-text="One"/> One
<br />
<input type='checkbox' name='test-link' value="2" data-text="Two" /> Two
<br />
<input type='checkbox' name='test-link' value="3" data-text="Three"/> Three           
<br />
```

And a change in your Javascript:

```
// If there is a checked checkbox
if($('[name=test-link]:checked').length > 0){
  $('#print-values').empty();
  $('#print-values').append("<span>You've checked:</span><br />");

    var v = $('[name=test-link]:checked').data('text');
    $('#print-values').append(v + "<br />");
}
```

I also updated your code to not need a .each, making it a bit cleaner.